# How-to deal with a lot of request on Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I host a Ruby on rail application (Mastodon) that use Postgres as datastore.

I got a lot of requests and it begets problems about pool that cause application need to wait to speak at Postgres.

I use Pgbouncer with this configuration :

```
max_client_conn = 2000
default_pool_size = 50
```

I have tweaked Postgres like that :

```
max_connections = 500
shared_buffers = 512MB
effective_cache_size = 1536MB
work_mem = 1048kB
maintenance_work_mem = 128MB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
```

The DB server is on a dedicated VPS with 2G ram.

The kind of error I got on the Rail side :

```
a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were in use
```

And sometimes error about requests timeout (Request ran for longer than 90000ms).

My Rail app spawn workers with this config :

```
  - WEB_CONCURRENCY=4
  - MAX_THREADS=10
  - DB_POOL=20
```

Any idea How to stop this busy Postgres pool problems ? 
Maybe it's a configuration issue.

Any other way to deal with that would be have Postgres slave for reads ?

I'm a bit exceeded with requests numbers..

Answer (score 0):

**I.** First tyne your Postgres to fit your RAM, OS, Postgres version, number of connections, etc. I use [pgtune.leopard.in.ua](http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/). Just enter parameters of your VPS and other options, and modify your postgresql.conf accordingly

**II.**
Then look at your database.yml. Often it allows maximum 5 connections (by default) in production. Try to increase this number to fit your needs:

```
#config/database.yml
production:
  ...
  pool: 20
```

It makes sense to put into pool maximum number of connections from I.

**III.** Optimize your database queries. Fix `n+1` queries, use [ActiveRecord.preload](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/preload), [includes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes). Gem [bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) can help you to identify problems with number of queries to your database